# Remove milliseconds and seconds from Joda time output

Tags: android, string, textview, jodatime

I am trying to output the time remaining to a certain date (15th of August in Madrid, Spain) and with my code I can get a TextView to display it correctly. However, it also displays milliseconds and seconds which I would like to remove, and also "months" that I would like to convert into days.

Could you give me a hand?

```
    DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Madrid");
    DateTime target = new DateTime(2015, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, timeZone);
    DateTime now = new DateTime(timeZone);
    Period period = new Period(now, target);

    PeriodFormatter formatter = PeriodFormat.getDefault();
    String output = formatter.print(period);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText(output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure Joda solution looks like:

```
   DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Madrid");
   DateTime target = new DateTime(2015, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, timeZone);
   DateTime now = new DateTime(timeZone);
   Period period = new Period(now, target);

   PeriodFormatter formatter = PeriodFormat.getDefault();
   String output = formatter.print(period);
   System.out.println(output); // 4 weeks, 2 days, 17 hours, 2 minutes, 10 seconds and 817 milliseconds

   period = new Period(
     now, 
     target, 
     PeriodType.dayTime().withSecondsRemoved().withMillisRemoved());
   output = formatter.print(period);
   System.out.println(output); // 30 days and 17 hours
```

The decisive change is using a specialized variation of [PeriodType](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html#dayTime--).

As long as you only want full English words (using `PeriodFormat.getDefault()`) Joda-Time is fine (there is built-in support for 9 languages only - other libs have better i18n-features). Otherwise, duration handling and formatting is not offered at all by standard Java as the other wrong answer of @VV pretends.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());  
    try {

        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        long timeStamp  = df.parse(formattedDate).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```